# Insert EmptyDataRow when gridview is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have tried the RowCreated event and created a GridViewRow with rowType DataRow and inserted a LinkButton which works fine. I have inserted the row as a footer row with no problems.

The problem occurs when I clear all the data from the database and the grid is empty with no data. After that the gridview stops showing the row I have created and won't even open a trace on the RowCreated event. So is there any solution or reason why this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a row shown when there is no data in the gridview try the EmptyDataTemplate

```
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Markup for row goes here
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

This will show data when there is no data in the data source